# Memory efficient padding a list

Tags: python

I have a list

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

of given length and I want to insert a certain element `'x'` after every item to get

```
ax = ['a', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'x']
```

Since the elements are of large size, I don't want to do a lot of `pop`s or sublists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: "Since the elements are of large size" - doesn't matter. It only matters how many there are. Python isn't going to copy them; list elements, variables, and just about all other ways of organizing objects only point to the objects they store.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh yes. I did tests with integers as items ((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the list is large, the best way is to go with a generator, like this

```
def interleave(my_list, filler):
    for item in my_list:
        yield item
        yield filler

print list(interleave(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'x'))
# ['a', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'x']
```

Or you can return a chained iterator like this

```
from itertools import chain, izip, repeat
def interleave(my_list, filler):
    return chain.from_iterable(izip(my_list, repeat(filler)))
```

1. `repeat(filler)` returns an iterator which gives `filler` infinite number of times.
2. `izip(my_list, repeat(filler))` returns an iterator, which picks one value at a time from both `my_list` and `repeat(filler)`. So, the output of `list(izip(my_list, repeat(filler)))` would look like this

   ```
   [('a', 'x'), ('b', 'x'), ('c', 'x')]
   ```
3. Now, all we have to do is flatten the data. So, we chain the result of `izip`, with `chain.from_iterable`, which gives one value at a time from the iterables.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) `izip`?

```
izip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
```

`izip_longest` can be used with a zero length list, a fillvalue, and combined via `chain.from_iterable` as follows:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip_longest('ABCD', '', fillvalue='x'))
>>> ['A', 'x', 'B', 'x', 'C', 'x', 'D', 'x']
```

Comment: The `'x'`s need to be interleaved with the original data, not chained after it.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Amended to izip.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use list comprehension for such things.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ax = [a[i/2] if i%2 == 0 else 'x' for i in range(2*len(a))]

print ax
['a', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'c', 'x']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate your list with a nested list comprehension

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ax = [c for y in a for x in y, 'x']
```

If you don't really need `ax` to be a list, you can make a generator like this

```
ax = (c for y in a for c in (y, 'x'))
for item in ax:
    # do something ...
```